# why does jQuery validate method work in Chrome but not IE?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I've got what may be a very simple thing, but as you can imagine, I'm getting no help from the IE Developer debugger! : )

I have this method that I added to make a length of a field conditional based on a select menu choice.

```
$.validator.addMethod("netwkdigit", function(value, element) {
var loannumentered = LOAN_NUM.value; 
if(acctloc.value != "Network" && loannumentered.length > 10 )  {
return false;  
}
 else {
 return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[0-9 ]+$/);;    
}
},    "Only 10 numbers allowed for the loan if network is not chosen.");
```

This works perfectly as I expect it to in Chrome, but not IE. The rest of the jQuery validate conditions are as shown.

```
            rules: {
            acctloc: {
                required: true
            },...
LOAN_NUM: {
required: true,
number: true,
netwkdigit: true,
minlength: 10, 
maxlength: 13,
},
```

and then there's other jQuery validate rules on there but they are irrelevant to this. In reference to the above, if the select choice is anything but Network I want it to only be 10 digits max, otherwise 13.

Now, in the method, I'm not referencing the form name per se there, but I have it already referenced in the main jQuery validate function for the form.
I wouldn't think that would matter, but I'm not sure.

Any feedback on this would be appreciated.

I added a small snippet above to show the acctloc reference.

Comment: What version of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works perfectly as I expect it to in Chrome, but not IE

As written, it should not work in any browser.

Your code...

```
LOAN_NUM: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    netwkdigit: true,
    minlength: 10, 
    maxlength: 13,
},
```

I don't know where you're getting the `acctloc` variable; and you cannot access `LOAN_NUM` from here...

```
$.validator.addMethod("netwkdigit", function(value, element) {
    var loannumentered = LOAN_NUM.value;  // <- here!
    if (acctloc.value != "Network" && loannumentered.length > 10 ) {
    ....
```

`LOAN_NUM` only represents the `name` attribute of the field being evaluated within the `rules` object of the `.validate()` method.  It's not a global variable that you can use anyplace else.

However, since `LOAN_NUM.value` seems to indicate that you want the "value" of this field, simply use the `value` argument as already provided by the `addMethod()` method...

```
$.validator.addMethod("netwkdigit", function(value, element) {
    var loannumentered = value; // value = the value of the field
    ....
```

Alternatively, if you want to access values of other fields from within `.addMethod()`, use jQuery:

```
$('[name="acctloc"]').val();  // value of 'acctloc'
$('[name="LOAN_NUM"]').val()  // value of 'LOAN_NUM'
```

Comment: In my above block, acctloc is the name of the select menu with several choices, with "Network" being one of those.  Basically if the user chooses Network, I would allow a length in the value of the field, LOAN_NUM, to be greater than 10. Otherwise, it would prohibit it. Again, it works perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE. That's what I can't resolve at the moment.

Comment: @BarryP, I constructed a demo based on your code and it's **impossible** that it works any browser... even Chrome is throwing `undefined` at `LOAN_NUM` and `acctloc`.  These have zero meaning within the context as you've presented.   http://jsfiddle.net/qkaz08bu/

Comment: @BarryP, if you want to access values of other fields from within `.addMethod()`, use jQuery:  `$('[name="acctloc"]').val()` and  `$('[name="LOAN_NUM"]').val()`

Comment: Thanks, Sparky, I'll give that a shot, but FWIW, my code is working successfully in BOTH FF and Chrome, just not IE. I'll try adding this part to the method, though. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! THAT ^^^ did it Sparky! I'm not too sure why FF and Chrome were being more tolerant with what I had in there before, but what I had above was being allowed by those two browsers. I plugged in the specific jQuery reference you listed and that worked accordingly! Many thanks! Let me know how I can mark it answered unless you do that.

Comment: @BarryP, I'm glad it's solved now.  However, when I try your original code in FF and Chrome, I get `undefined` for those keywords because they are considered as **undefined** variables... so I have no idea why you think that was working before.

Comment: @BarryP, click the checkmark by the voting arrows to mark it answered.  Thanks